# content-type = video/abst

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

[image: Capture of a HTTP trace containing Live TV stream]

In the live TV over HTTP capture, I see the HTTP traffic carrying the 'video/abst' payload. I kind of googled it, but did not find any specific details.

Can someone please explain what this content is and why it is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

video/abst content-type it's used for a streamed video. One video it's divided in a lot of segments and they're downloaded when they're needed by the player.

This kind of streaming cannot be downloaded within usual download tools.

You need to use applications to catch the Streaming, like [StreamTransport](http://www.streamtransport.com/web-video-downloader/) or [Replay Media Catcher](http://applian.com/replay-media-catcher/)

Answer (score 1):

Those are the HTTP headers sent by live streaming software, It's used for HTTP Dynamic Streaming.

ABST file is a Adobe HDS Bootstrap. Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS) is a solution that allows you to stream live and on-demand content over HTTP to Adobe Flash Player. WowZa Streaming uses this technology too.

> HTTP Dynamic Streaming enables on-demand and live adaptive bitrate video delivery of standards-based MP4 media over regular HTTP connections. HDS lets you leverage existing cache infrastructures and provides tools for integration of content preparation into existing encoding workflows.